# SwiftUI: NavigationView focus on last selected NavigationLink

Tags: swiftui, focus, swiftui-navigationlink

maybe a very simple problem:
I use a navigation with a long list of entries. If the user returns from the navigationLink the list starts on the first item. How can I set the focus on the last selected navigationLink so the user don't need to scroll from the beginning again.
My app is for blind people so the scrolling from above isn't an easy thing.

´´´
struct CategoryDetailView: View {

```
@EnvironmentObject var blindzeln: BLINDzeln
@AppStorage ("version") var version: Int = 0
@State var shouldRefresh: Bool = false
@State private var searchText = ""
let categoryTitle: String
let catID: Int

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        List {
            ForEach(blindzeln.results.filter { searchText.isEmpty || ($0.title.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) || $0.textBody.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)) }, id: \.entryID){ item in
           
                    NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetailViewStandard(item: item, isFavorite: false, catID: catID)) {DisplayEntryView(item: item, catID: catID)}.listRowSeparatorTint(.primary).listRowSeparator(.hidden) 
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always), prompt: "") {}
        
        .navigationTitle(categoryTitle)

        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .listStyle(.inset)
    }
    .task(){
        await blindzeln.decodeCategoryData(showCategory: categoryTitle)
    }
    .onAppear(){
    blindzeln.resetData()
    }
}
```

}
´´´

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this approach, using the `List` with `selection`, such
as in this example code. It does not scroll back to the beginning of the list
after selecting a destination.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selections = Set<Thing>()
    @State var things: [Thing] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(things, selection: $selections){ thing in
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("destination-\(thing.val)")) {
                    Text("item-\(thing.val)")
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            (0..<111).forEach{things.append(Thing(val: $0))}
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

Since there are so many elements missing from you code, I can only guess
and suggest something like this:

```
struct CategoryDetailView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var blindzeln: BLINDzeln
    @AppStorage ("version") var version: Int = 0
    
    @State var shouldRefresh: Bool = false
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    @State private var selections = Set<Thing>() // <-- same type as item in the List
    
    let categoryTitle: String
    let catID: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // -- here
            List(blindzeln.results.filter { searchText.isEmpty || ($0.title.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) || $0.textBody.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)) },
                 id: \.entryID,
                 selection: $selections){ item in
                
                NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetailViewStandard(item: item, isFavorite: false, catID: catID)) {
                    DisplayEntryView(item: item, catID: catID)
                }
                .listRowSeparatorTint(.primary).listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always), prompt: "") {}
        
        .navigationTitle(categoryTitle)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .listStyle(.inset)
        .task{
            await blindzeln.decodeCategoryData(showCategory: categoryTitle)
        }
        .onAppear{
            blindzeln.resetData()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Sorry, workingdog, but I don't really understand how to adapt your solution into my code. Do you have maybe some more hints?

Comment: updated my answer with some `hints`.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand the Set<Thing>(). But this didn't solve the problem. If I'm returning from the NavigationLink the list starts at the beginning. Maybe I have to use AccessibilityFocusState property. Your answer leads me to the right direction (hopefully) :-)

Comment: Since we do not have a reproducible example of your code, that compiles and run, I can only guess and suggest you try to comment out the `blindzeln.resetData()`, see if the problem is due to that. Does my example code works for you?.

Comment: Yes, thank you. the code works fine. after returning from NavigationLink the list shows the right row. but the accessibilityFocus starts from the beginning. removing the resetData() makes no difference...